# How to implement up/down voting in Firebase inside a recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase

I have yet to find something similar to this. I am trying to create a news app that also includes up and down voting. My Recyclerview is displaying the items in the correct order but I am not able to only update the specific upvote value.

Answer (score 0):

try to code onclick listener for upvote button inside your onbindviewholder method of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Each item in the list should have a unique id. I'm not sure what exactly your RecyclerView is displaying but you can try making an id based on the date and time and the user's username or something else that uniquely identifies the item in the list. Then store each id for every item in the list in Firebase. For each item, add a separate click listener for up and down votes. When one of them is clicked, send that item's id to Firebase and get the counter associated with that id and increment or decrement it based on what the user did. Then Update the UI to display the new value.

Of course I simplified it a lot but that should be the gist of it. Hope this helped.